# Delete all the lines in a file that contains a specific character

Tags: perl, bash, unix, command-line, awk

I want to delete all the rows/lines in a file that has a specific character,  '?' in my case. I hope there is a single line command in Bash or AWK or Perl. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are already grep, sed and perl solutions - only for fun, pure bash one:

```
pattern='?'
while read line
do
    [[ "$line" =~ "$pattern" ]] || echo "$line"
done
```

translated

- for every line on the STDIN
- match it for the pattern `=~`
- and if the match is not successful `||` - print out the line

Answer (score 9):

You can use `sed` to modify the file "in-place":

```
sed -i "/?/d" file
```

Alternatively, use grep:

```
grep -v "?" file > newfile.txt
```

Comment: You can use `-i` with GNU sed; it is not standard on other versions, in general.

Answer (score 6):

Even better, just a single line using `sed`

```
sed '/?/d' input
```

use `-i` to edit file in place.

Comment: and from my understanding you can't do that in perl , right? `perl -pe '/?/d'` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -i -ne'/\?/ or print' file
```

or

```
perl -i -pe's/^.*?\?.*//s' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '!($0~/?/){print $0}' file_name
```